# cannot retrieve getAdditionalInformation() from Payment object

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am getting empty array from `getAdditionalInformation()` on Payment object. The transaction details are attached to the order. Somehow i cannot retrieve them. I get empty array. Here is my code

```
$magorder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($valor);
$payment = $magorder->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
```

please someone point me to right direction. Thanks

Comment: i did not understand your question..

Comment: are you sure that tour object has additional information? If you look at the functions getAdditionalInformation() in core code then they return empty array if there is no result or specific key is not used for asking information from those methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. The  code is bellow

```
$magorder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($valor);
            $payment = $magorder->getPayment();

            $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->getCollection()
                ->addPaymentIdFilter($payment->getId());

            foreach ($collection as $col)
            {
                print_r ($col->getAdditionalInformation());
            }
```